# Remove decimals from the approval email

Tags: approval-process

I have a leave request approval flow in place which works perfectly. But when an approval email is sent the the approver, Number Of Days (calculated column), shows as 0.500000000000 instead of 0.5 and shows 1.000000000000000 instead of 1. It should show as it is, for example 1=1, 0.5=0.5, 2.5=2.5.

Does anyone has a solution to this? Any help or guidance on this will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Niki

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using `formatNumber(<Number Of Days column reference>, '0.00', 'en-us')` expression for this column. Let me know if this works

Comment: Hi, 
I tried to enter the formula in the flow in the expressions. But it says invalid expression. Sorry can you tell me if i am making any mistake in writing the formula. I am not a technical person so just trying to figure out.

Comment: You have to use correct reference for your number of days column in the expression. You can add screenshot to your original question how you have used the expressions and flow.

Comment: What do you mean by correct reference? Can you give an example?

Comment: I have added some screenshots of my flow. Let me know if you need any more information. Also i was trying to add the expression in the Details of Start and wait for an approval.

Comment: You have to use correct reference to column value in this format: `formatNumber(triggerBody()?['NoOfDays'], '0.00', 'en-us')`. Where, `NoOfDays` is the internal name of your column in SharePoint. Also, screenshots you attached are not clear - cannot see the formula used in flow.

Comment: Hi I have attached a screenshot. The red box is where i am trying to add a formula in the expressions field... Also can you tell me what should be the triggerbody .... should it be update item? and should there be any space between ['NumberOfDays'] and '0.00'.... I tried everything but nothing is working... Is it the right place where i am trying to add the formula?

Comment: You are adding the formula at correct place. I assumed you are reading Number of days column value from flow trigger - first block in your flow (For eg. When an item is created). `triggerBody` is the outputs from this trigger. If you are trying to get the value from trigger, use same. If you are trying to get the value from outputs of update item action, you can use it instead of triggerBody. Also, space is not required in formula. Just follow the syntax with 3 parameters separated by `,` like: `formatNumber(triggerBody()?['NoOfDays'], '0.00', 'en-us')`

Comment: Hi I am getting above errors while trying to run the flow. I have added some screenshots for the same.